# Entity classes in JPA cannot have final data members in it

Tags: jpa, final

I am adding a final data member in the entity class in JPA and it is giving me error that the java field for attribute "jobBand" is final. 
Is there anything wrong in keeping the final fields in an entity class?

Comment: Yes, there is. JPA can't populate your field if it's final. And you're in violation of the spec, as the error message tells you.

Comment: @ JB Nizet Ok I got that, I just wanted to see if final data members are allowed in an entity class or not. If I apply @Transient annotation on top of the final data member, then there isn't any compilation error. So basically any data member that you intend to persist should not be kept as final is what the spec says???

Comment: Yes. The exact words are "The entity class must not be final. No methods or persistent instance variables of the entity class may be final.". The spec is available for free here: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet  :)

Comment: But I just tried, am able to define final instance method in the entity class and same is getting successfully called on the entity's object too.